# ZipException thrown when using jogl in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jogl, buildpath

This is Eclipse project build path:

[image]

files in project:

```
rob@work:~/git/thegame$ ll lib/linux32/
total 708
drwxr-xr-x 2 rob rob   4096 Mar 22 02:37 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 rob rob   4096 Mar 22 02:23 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 rob rob   8704 Mar 10 14:00 libgluegen-rt.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 rob rob 666380 Mar 11 03:22 libjogl_desktop.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 rob rob   5944 Mar 11 03:22 libnativewindow_awt.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 rob rob  26604 Mar 11 03:22 libnativewindow_x11.so
rob@work:~/git/thegame$ ll jar/
total 3308
drwxr-xr-x 3 rob rob    4096 Mar 22 02:28 ./
drwxr-xr-x 8 rob rob    4096 Mar 22 02:22 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 rob rob  289171 Mar 10 14:00 gluegen-rt.jar
drwxr-xr-x 4 rob rob    4096 Mar 22 02:28 javadocs/
-rw-r--r-- 1 rob rob 3082066 Mar 11 03:23 jogl-all.jar
```

Error when trying to execute application:

```
Catched ZipException: error in opening zip file, while addNativeJarLibsImpl(classFromJavaJar class com.jogamp.common.os.Platform, classJarURI jar:file:/home/rob/git/thegame/jar/gluegen-rt.jar!/com/jogamp/common/os/Platform.class, nativeJarBaseName gluegen-rt-natives-linux-i586.jar): [ file:/home/rob/git/thegame/jar/gluegen-rt.jar -> file:/home/rob/git/thegame/jar/ ] + gluegen-rt-natives-linux-i586.jar -> slim: jar:file:/home/rob/git/thegame/jar/gluegen-rt-natives-linux-i586.jar!/
Catched ZipException: error in opening zip file, while addNativeJarLibsImpl(classFromJavaJar class jogamp.nativewindow.NWJNILibLoader, classJarURI jar:file:/home/rob/git/thegame/jar/jogl-all.jar!/jogamp/nativewindow/NWJNILibLoader.class, nativeJarBaseName jogl-all-natives-linux-i586.jar): [ file:/home/rob/git/thegame/jar/jogl-all.jar -> file:/home/rob/git/thegame/jar/ ] + jogl-all-natives-linux-i586.jar -> slim: jar:file:/home/rob/git/thegame/jar/jogl-all-natives-linux-i586.jar!/
Catched IOException: TempJarCache: addNativeLibs: jar:file:/home/rob/git/thegame/jar/jogl-all-natives-linux-i586.jar!/, previous load attempt failed, while addNativeJarLibsImpl(classFromJavaJar class jogamp.nativewindow.NWJNILibLoader, classJarURI jar:file:/home/rob/git/thegame/jar/jogl-all.jar!/jogamp/nativewindow/NWJNILibLoader.class, nativeJarBaseName jogl-all-natives-linux-i586.jar): [ file:/home/rob/git/thegame/jar/jogl-all.jar -> file:/home/rob/git/thegame/jar/ ] + jogl-all-natives-linux-i586.jar -> slim: jar:file:/home/rob/git/thegame/jar/jogl-all-natives-linux-i586.jar!/
Catched IOException: TempJarCache: addNativeLibs: jar:file:/home/rob/git/thegame/jar/jogl-all-natives-linux-i586.jar!/, previous load attempt failed, while addNativeJarLibsImpl(classFromJavaJar class jogamp.nativewindow.NWJNILibLoader, classJarURI jar:file:/home/rob/git/thegame/jar/jogl-all.jar!/jogamp/nativewindow/NWJNILibLoader.class, nativeJarBaseName jogl-all-natives-linux-i586.jar): [ file:/home/rob/git/thegame/jar/jogl-all.jar -> file:/home/rob/git/thegame/jar/ ] + jogl-all-natives-linux-i586.jar -> slim: jar:file:/home/rob/git/thegame/jar/jogl-all-natives-linux-i586.jar!/
```

`Main.java`

```
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.media.opengl.GLCapabilities;
import javax.media.opengl.GLProfile;
import javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // setup OpenGL Version 2
        GLProfile profile = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL2);
        GLCapabilities capabilities = new GLCapabilities(profile);

        // The canvas is the widget that's drawn in the JFrame
        GLCanvas glcanvas = new GLCanvas(capabilities);
        glcanvas.addGLEventListener(new Renderer());
        glcanvas.setSize( 300, 300 );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame( "Hello World" );
        frame.getContentPane().add( glcanvas);

        // shutdown the program on windows close event
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent ev) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        frame.setSize( frame.getContentPane().getPreferredSize() );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you download the JARs directly, some web browsers might wrap it into a ZIP file for "security" reasons. Rather download the 7z archive [here](http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-current/archive/jogamp-all-platforms.7z) and take the JARs it contains. You should follow [these detailed instructions](http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE#Eclipse_IDE_user_library), it should work in Eclipse.

I remind you that the separated native libraries are no longer required in JOGL 2, rather use the JARs containing the native libraries, it is a lot less error prone, just put them into the same directory than the Java libraries relying on them (jogl-all.jar and gluegen-rt.jar).

Comment: Ok. Yes, just put jogl-all.jar, gluegen-rt.jar and all their JARs containing native libraries into the same directory and put only jogl-all.jar and gluegen-rt.jar into the classpath. If you use JOAL and JOCL, put joal.jar and jocl.jar into the classpath too.